# How to multiply attributes of classes efficiently? [Python 3]

Tags: python, python-3.x

As an example, let's say I have the following:

```
class abcde:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y

z = abcde(5, 6)
w = abcde(10, 3)
```

If I wanted to create an instance of `abcde`, say `zw`, so that the values of its attributes were the product of the corresponding attributes of instances `z` and `wt`, I would simply do:

```
zw = abcde(50, 18)
```

But my actual code has 20 attributes for `abcde` and I need a generic way of multiplying these attributes together, because if I have 20 classes which each have 20 attributes, that's 400 figures to write out, then including mixes (which there are a lot) I'll be there forever. I want it to be something like:

```
zw = abcde(z)*abcde(w)
```

Please let me know if there's a way I can do this.

Comment: Are the attributes ordered? Does `x` always come before `y`, come before, `z`, etc? If so, perhaps you should have *one* attribute which stores a tuple... Multiplying two tuples element-wise is easy: `map(operator.mul, (5,6), (10,3))`.

Comment: I don't know why you want to use classes here: that's not really what they're for. A simple function would be more appropriate.

Comment: What are you actually attempting to accomplish? This sounds like a potential XY problem.

Answer (score 4):

```
class Abcde:
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x=x
        self.y=y

    def __mul__(self, other):
        return Abcde(self.x * other.x, self.y * other.y)

    def __repr__(self):
        return "Abcde({}, {})".format(self.x, self.y)

z = Abcde(5,6)
w = Abcde(10,3)

zw = z * w    # = Abcde(50, 18)
```

or, more generally:

```
from collections import namedtuple

def namedvector(typename, field_names):
    newclass = namedtuple(typename, field_names)
    newclass.__mul__ = lambda self, other: newclass(*(a * b for a,b in zip(self, other)))
    return newclass

Abcde = namedvector("Abcde", ["x", "y", "z", "t", "u"])

z = Abcde(5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
w = Abcde(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

zw = z * w

print(zw)     # => Abcde(x=5, y=12, z=21, t=32, u=45)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate the multiply of all arguments (20 attributes) you can firs define a function for calculate the multiply and then use that function with `zip` in a list comprehension :

```
>>> def mult(x):
...     mul=1
...     for i in x :
...         mul=mul*i
...     return mul
... 
>>> l1=[2,3,4]
>>> l2=[3,4,5]
>>> l3=[7,2,3]
>>> [mult(x) for x in zip(l1,l2,l3)]
[42, 24, 60]
```

then if we suppose you have 3 class `z`,`w`,`x` you can pass the result of preceding code to your final class :

```
>>> zwx(42, 24, 60)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try like this:

```
>>> class abcde:
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.data = []
...     def num(self,*x):
...         self.data.append(x)
...     def mul(self):
...         return [ x*y for x,y in zip(*self.data) ]
... 
>>> initlize = abcde()
>>> initlize.num(5,6)
>>> initlize.num(10,3)
>>> initlize.mul()
[50, 18]
```